# What exactly constitutes the worst case input of various sorting algorithms?

Tags: algorithms, asymptotics

This is related to the [this question.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3273869/407302)

**I naively used to think that the worst case of all sorting algorithms was an input given in descending order. But it seems that I was wrong.**

For example according to this post, [the worst case of merge sort looks quite different than just an array with numbers in descending order](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/find-a-permutation-that-causes-worst-case-of-merge-sort/).

So my question is that **what exactly constitutes a worst case scenario of an algorithm.** Can this be formally represented ? And is there a way/technique of deriving/proving this from the algorithm?

Answer (score 3):

The formal definition of a worst case scenario is that it's an input for which for a given size the algorithm takes the maximum number of steps. There may be more than one such input.

As you discovered, the set of worst case scenarios depends on the algorithm. There's no generic way to find one without knowing the algorithm.

Comment: I would add "for a given size of input" to your definition.

Comment: @RobertIsrael Done thanks. You could have.

Comment: For a given $n$, you can do a brute-force search over the possible inputs of size $n$ to find one that takes the most steps.  But there is no guarantee that you can generalize this to all $n$.

Comment: @EthanBolker Yes but is there a formal way to compute them?

Comment: @ng.newbie Not in an algorithm indeoendent way. For each algorithm (or perhaps class of algorithms) you might be able to find/derive a way to calculate the  worst case inputs.